# how to pragmatically add a folder to an already present storage directory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a controller that generates a folder for any user that registers with a laravel app. However, I'm also trying to add folders to their user directories in storage. For instance, if a user registers, they have in their directory folders for images, files, contacts, etc. How would I do this in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: wit native PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php ... is Laravel community really gowing towards ["How to add two numbers in JavaScript"](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/20091116-so-large.gif) level?

Comment: @tereško Well it can get nasty when you deal with different storage systems, so the question is definitely legit :D

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be calling a function after creating the newly registered user (mostly after the `User::create([..]);` line). In the function you can call

```
Storage::makeDirectory("path/to/your/dir/".$user->name);
```

to create the wanted directory. If you want to add an image directory in the newly created folder, just use the same method again.

```
Storage::makeDirectory("path/to/your/dir/".$user->name."/img");
```

When you want to add a lot of subfolders, go for an array with the folder strings and a foreach loop.

```
$folders = ["/img","/files","/somethingElse"];
foreach($folders as $folder){
    Storage::makeDirectory("path/to/your/dir/" . $user->name . $folder);
}
```

Comment: I have that in the code already. What I'm trying to do now is add other folders to that folder that belongs to the user in that directory. If a user has their own folder, how do I add an images folder to that directory?

Comment: For instance, the file path would be app/storage/app/public/{ username }/images. I also want to add other folders after the username folder.

Comment: @metaco57 Well you can use the same method again. Pass in the user/username at least and go for: `Storage::makeDirectory("path/to/your/dir/".$user->name."/images");`

Comment: @metaco57 when you have that code it was much better to show what you have tried in stead of letting us guess

Comment: My code is the exact way that @manniL is. My question is how do I add multiple folders under the folder with the username at the same time?

Comment: Well, then your question wasn't posed very well :D @metaco57

But why don't you go for a simple foreach loop and array map? :D

Comment: I actually haven't thought of that. Guess its worth a shot. Thanks!

Comment: That's great @metaco57 :) Please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer if it solves your problem!

Answer (score -1):

Using a foreach loop with an array map did the trick. I now have all current folders inside the user directory in storage. Here is a sample of the code:

```
$folders = ['images', 'files', 'contacts'];

    foreach ($folders as $folder)
    {
        Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory($data['name'] . '/' . $folder);
    }
```